# Unity access collider as public variable on different gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I create instances of a prefab, (which is two rectangles with a gap in the middle), and if the player sprite collides with the collider in the gap, the score will increase.

I have a boxCollider2D on a prefab object, and want this collider as a public variable on a separate sprite, so I can access it on my script on the sprite.

So currently, col, is the collider the sprite is interacting with which is:

barrier(Clone) (UnityEngine.BoxCollider2D))

and my colliderBox is:

barrier (UnityEngine.BoxCollider2D)

So the only difference is one is from the prefab, and one is from the the objected created using the prefab.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col){

    if (col.CompareTag ("barrier") && col != colliderBox) {
        Debug.Log (col);
        Debug.Log (colliderBox);
        SceneManager.LoadScene (mainMenu);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it, you want to have your collider as a public variable, try something like:

```
public class PrefabObject: MonoBehaviour {

        public BoxCollider2D boxCollider;

        private void Start()
        {
            this.boxCollider = this.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        }
    }

    public class OtherObject: MonoBehaviour {

                public PrefabObject prefabObject;
                private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;
                private void Start()
                {
                    this.boxCollider = prefabObject.boxCollider;
                    //or also this.boxCollider = prefabObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>(); 
                }
            }
```

If there is no PrefabObject script attached to the GameObject that have the boxCollider2D, and only have the collider component attached, the OtherObject will be like:

```
public class OtherObject: MonoBehaviour {

                public GameObject prefabObject; //Here is the change!
                private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;
                private void Start()
                {
                    this.boxCollider = prefabObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
                }
            }
```

Comment: So this will create the public variable on the object with a script, but my boxCollider is on a different object to the one with the script, how can I get the boxCollider from the different object, to the one with the script?

Comment: @Mattattack I have updated the answer, you only have to reference the prefab Object to the otherObject, so inside otherObject can reach and store the boxCollider2D from PrefabObject. Notice that you don't need to attach the script PrefabObject to the object with a ColliderBox2D, you can grave it as a simple component.